# How to make a nested for-loop with two individual loops?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I am tasked with running a for-loop which initially finds the value of funds in a mans investment account from his 41-65th birthday. Here is the code below.

```
mu = 0.076 ###Mean
sigma = 0.167 ###Standard deviation
np.exp(np.random.normal(mu, sigma,))


u = .076 ###set variables 
bi = 50000 ###set variables 

empty = [] ###empty list
for i in range(25): ###range for birthdays 40-65
    bi = ((bi) * (np.exp(np.random.normal(mu, sigma))))
    empty.append(bi)
print(empty)
len(empty) ##making sure my lists match up

roundedempty = [ '%.2f' % elem for elem in empty ]
    age = [41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,
                   60,61,62,63,64,65]
    len(age) ##making sure my lists match up
    investing = pd.DataFrame({"Balance":roundedempty, "Age":age})
    investing.set_index('Age', inplace=True)
    investing

When I print this out it give me this: 
Age   Balance           
41    53948.13
.........
65    334294.72
```

Now I am tasked with simulating this 100,000 times, but I am not sure how to nest another loop within that first set of code.

```
mu = 0.076 ###Mean
sigma = 0.167 ###Standard deviation
bi = 50000

lognormvals = np.zeros(100000)
for i in range(100000):
            lognormvals[i] = ((bi) * (np.exp(np.random.normal(mu, sigma,))))
print(lognormvals)
np.mean(lognormvals)
```

This is what I want, but it is only doing it for his 41st birthday. I am tasked with trying to find the means of each birthday from his 41-65th. How can I nest this loop within the first loop to solve this?

```
My Shot at solving:
def InvestmentSim():
    mu = 0.076 ###Mean
    sigma = 0.167 ###Standard deviation
    np.exp(np.random.normal(mu, sigma,))


    u = .076 ###set variables 
    bi = 50000 ###set variables 

    empty = [] ###empty list
    for i in range(25): ###range for birthdays 40-65
        bi = ((bi) * (np.exp(np.random.normal(mu, sigma))))
        empty.append(bi)

    roundedempty = [ '%.2f' % elem for elem in empty ]
    age = [41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,
                   60,61,62,63,64,65]
    len(age) ##making sure my lists match up
    investing = pd.DataFrame({"Balance":roundedempty, "Age":age})
    investing.set_index('Age', inplace=True)
    a = investing.iloc[24]['Balance']
    return a

def AverageSim(iterations):
    results = []
    for n in range (0, iterations):
        a = InvestmentSim()
        results.append(a)
        print(results)
    return myresult

myresult = AverageSim(1)
myresults = np.array(myresult) # Turn the list of values into an array
mean = np.mean(myresults)
median = np.median(myresults)
print(mean, median)
```

Instead of doing all the balance for each year instead I just singled out the balance on his 65th birthday and set it equal to (a). Is this how my code should work? Doesn't seem to be running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to repeat the first snippet n times, then I'd suggest wrappning your code for the simulation, up in a function which you can call repeatedly in a for loop. The function should return your expected values, and the for loop should collect the results. After the loop is finished you can do further calculations with the loop such as mean.

```
# Your simulation as a callable function
def InvestmentSim():
    # your first code
    return investing


def AverageSims(iterations):

    # Initialise an empty list to collect the results
    results = []

    for n in range (0, iterations):
        investing = InvestmentSim()
        results.append(investing)
        # Adds investing to the end of the list

    # Returns a list of all the dataframes which you can use for future
    # calculations.
    # Or do the desired calculations here and return only those results.
    return results

myresult = AverageSims(100000)
```

Note that with 100,000 iterations you will get a very long list of fairly bulky dataframes. So instead you may want to do some calculations in place or pull out relevant results from each iteration and discard the rest. For example you could just save the start and end balances from each sim and append those to lists and return those.
I'd give an example but I don't use pandas so I don't want to guess at the syntax. The basic principle is the same though: Initialise some blank lists and append the results in the for loop. 
Calculations will probably be simpler to set up if you turn the finished list(s) into numpy arrays using `np.array(somelist)`

## Edit

Your code isn't running because you're calling the AverageSims function **inside** the AverageSims function, so you never actually get to that call. You need to move that call outside so it's executed when you run your script. The simplest way is to write the call the same way I did above, outside any function and without indentation.

Also, if your AverageSims() function doesn't have the return mysresults line, it will return None instead. That's not a problem unless you want to use results later on. 
If you don't want to keep the results and are happy with printing them out as you do now, you can also call the function without equating it to a variable:

```
def InvestmentSim():
    # your first code
    return investing


def AverageSims(iterations):
    # Repeatedly do the simulation, collect results

    # Returning the results, if you don't need them you can omit this:
    return myresult


# Now call the AverageSims function, otherwise it will never be executed. Note: No indent.  
myresults = AverageSims(100000) # If you're returning the results
# OR:
AverageSims(100000) # If you don't return the results

myresult = np.array(myresult) # Turn the list of values into an array
mean = np.mean(myresult)
median = np.median(myresult)
print(mean, median)
```

Comment: What are iterations in my case?

Comment: The number of iterations the for loop goes through. `range(0,n)` basically goes from 0, 1, 2, .., n-1 (because zero-indexing), so the simulation is repeated n times.

Comment: I included my shot at trying to solve it in my original post. Can you see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I edited my answer. The short version is, you're calling the Averaging function from inside itself, so that call never actually happens.

Comment: Now I get the error though that AverageSims does not exist.

Comment: Slight nomenclature mixup perhaps? I used AverageSim**s**, you used AverageSim.

Comment: Okay sweet I got it. The code is taking forever to run it 100,000 times so I just set it to 10 for the time being. Say I just wanted to single out his last balance on his 65th birthday.  The code a = investing.iloc[24]['Balance'] does this, but when I run it it gives me the data for his birthdays 41-65. I know you said you didn't have the best of knowledge with pandas, but can you give me a hint if you can?

Comment: If you update your code to the current version you're running I can take another look.

Comment: You're still printing your ´empty´ list with each iteration. If you comment out the ´print´ statement in ´InvestmentSim()´ your code should also run a bit more smoothly. The real results are in the ´results´ list in `AverageSims()`, so you could print that. If your iloc line is correct that should just be a list of all the final balances for all simulations.

Comment: Okay I got that now it is printing just the last value in that list. How can I then manipulate that list of 100,000 values? Like say I wanted to use the function mean and median with it? How do I take it out of that loop and say put it into an array that I can manipulate? As soon as I take that variable out of the AverageSim() it says it doesn't exist.

Comment: Edited. The quickest way is to use numpy's mean, median etc. functions to get those values. In my edited version above the resultslist that is generated is returned and then processed. You could also add the calculations and printing to the `AverageSims()` function directly. Numpy also works with lists but in the example the list is converted to an array first just to be on the safe side.

Comment: Tried to play around with it,  but keep getting this error."" unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'int'""

Comment: If you're doing the calculations _outside_ `AverageSims()`, you must have the `return results` line (put in the name of the variable you want to return). Otherwise python implicitly returns ´None`, hence the error.

Comment: I just did that and still nada. Sorry I suck at coding this is an annoying process. Do you mind looking at my code again? I just updated it with what I have.

Comment: Should be `return results` in `AverageSim()`
The return statement sends back a variable from a function to where the function call originated from. If you call a a function like this: 
`myvariable = SomeFunction()`
and SomeFunction has this:
'return somefunctionvariable'
Python will run the function called "SomeFunction" and put "myvariable" equal to "somefunctionvariable". You can then work with the result outside the function by referring to "myvariable".

Comment: New error: cannot perform reduce with flexible type. I assume this is because our array contains strings?

Comment: Possibly. Like I said, I don't use Pandas so I can't follow the syntax or run the code. But the list `results` should _only_ contain numbers, i.e. the balance numbers you want to average together. It should look something like [100.34 ,2200.42,1234.24, 234.11, 2345.67], which is what I assumed for the calculations. (you could check by printing the list before conversion attempts) Any strings like Pandas descriptors or similar in there will cause errors.

Comment: They look like this. ['164764.89', '144366.97', '366800.85']

Comment: Okay, so your pandas line returns the numbers as strings and you need to turn them back into numbers using `float()`:
`a = float(investing.iloc[24]['Balance'])`

Comment: Sweet thank you so much! My computer spazzes out when I change the simulations from 10,000-100,000. Is there any way to modify my code to make it run without having to actually compute it 100,000 times on my computer?

Answer (score 0):

You can just put a loop inside another loop:

```
for x in range(10):
    for y in range(5):
         print(x,y)
```

I your case it would also be advisable to put the inner loop into a function, and run that function in the outer loop. Like this:

```
def calculate(*args):
    # do your calculations here that include a loop
    return result

for x in range(100000):
    calculate()
```